# Get Private & Public Key For Encryption and Decryption of Mails in Lotus Domino

Tags: java, security, lotus-domino, lotus

I know id file contains Private and Public Key. Public Key is inside Certificate under Id File and Private Key is inside id file but not in the certificate. 
The Question is how can i get those keys through my java code . I need to encrypt and decrypt mails .

Answer (score 1):

Public keys can be found in the Domino Directory.  You don't need to do anything special to encrypt emails.  The Notes APIs will do that for you automatically.

Decryption is another story.   The whole point of a private key is that it is *private*.  The private key in your current ID file is available to you after you type in your password, but you can't access any other private key.   Private keys are encrypted using a password-derived key and if there was any way to get around that encryption, it would not be private!

So, if you are trying to decrypt messages sent to users, the only way to do that is to switch the current ID to that user's ID file, using that user's password.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . 
Suppose i have a Document 'd' . My id file is 'sachin.id' How can i encrypt it and decrypt it in java? How can i switch id in my java code.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no supported way to switch IDs directly within Java code.  

The C API call SECFMSwitchToIDFile will do it, but you will have to work out the details of calling it from Java -- and I'm not 100% sure that the Notes Java classes will behave as expected if you do this.

Comment: Another way I've heard some people approach this is by using Session.SetEnvironmentVar to alter the KeyFilename entry in notes.ini to point to your ID file, then starting up a new Java program, whose job will be to do the work and then change the KeyFilename back to what it was.  If the ID file has a password, you will need to enter it manually -- or you can use the Extension Manager features of the Notes C API to provide the password.  I doubt this will work well if your Java code is runnning as an agent.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a shared certificate across all users and add that to your Java code.

The following sample shows you how to create a self-signed certificate.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Connecting_to_a_Domino_server_over_SSL_in_Java_using_a_self_signed_certificate._