# how to read public key in lotus notes in java from id file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

how to read public key and private key in lotus notes in java from id file.i referred to this link click.[[Get Private & Public Key For Encrption and Decryption of Mails in Lotus Domino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481780/get-private-public-key-for-encrption-and-decryption-of-mails-in-lotus-domino].but) i could not get much from that and since the questioner has not answered the question..i am asking it again.Any help plz?

Answer (score 1):

The public key can be read from the Domino Directory, not from the ID file.

There is no API for reading the private key or public key from the ID file.

Comment: then how one can achieve decryption of mail document in lotus notes.suppose i am trying to read a document that is encrypted how can  one decrypt that mail and read it.what i am doing is i have written a webservice in java for reading mails but for the encrypted mail i am not getting the body part.

Comment: See the comments on my answer to the other quesiton that you previously linked. You have to actually switch the code's current ID file, or perhaps set up and start an external process that runs under that ID. It's not easy to decrypt someone else's email. It's not supposed to be easy! IBM has done this for security purposes - to keep private keys really private. They have protected the key inside the password-protected ID file, and they do not want any code to have access to it except there own. That way they can guaranteed that it will never be stored in a less secure manner.